# Angular Lazy Loading ( the module has not been imported into your module)

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 5.2.10 and trying to make application to lazy loading.so creating new module for `AuditorloginComponent` and i have removed my `AuditorloginComponent` from `app.module.ts`

auditorlogin.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AuditorloginRoutingModule,FormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [AuditorloginComponent]
})
export class AuditorloginModule { }
```

auditorlogin-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: '',
    component: AuditorloginComponent
}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AuditorloginRoutingModule { }
```

app.routing.ts

I have added `loadChildren`

```
 {
    path: 'auditorlogin',
    loadChildren: 'app/auditor/auditorlogin/auditorlogin-routing.module#AuditorloginRoutingModule',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
```

But i am getting

```
core.js:1449 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Component AuditorloginComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.

Error: Component AuditorloginComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module
```

Kindly tell to me where is my mistake?

Comment: Tried not working @Faisal

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you don't have your component in `AuditorloginRoutingModule` `declarations:[...]`

Comment: Thanks @dee zg got it my mistake

Comment: Don't think, this will work, because, it will throw error like ' the component is part of the declarations of 2 modules'

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is in `AuditorloginRoutingModule` . you must be added `AuditorloginComponent` in declration like this

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: '',
    component: AuditorloginComponent
}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  declarations: [
    // components that are used will be added here.
    AuditorloginComponent]
})
export class AuditorloginRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 3):

You are only lazy loading the routing module, while you should load the `AuditorloginModule` which then uses the `AuditorloginRoutingModule` for routing and not the other way round.

```
{
    path: 'auditorlogin',
    loadChildren: 'app/auditor/auditorlogin/auditorlogin.module#AuditorloginModule',
    pathMatch: 'full'
},
```

Comment: This is working for me.. I think.. this should be accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

Change **AuditorloginModule** to

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AuditorloginRoutingModule,FormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [AuditorloginComponent],
  export: [AuditorloginComponent]
})
export class AuditorloginModule { }
```

And then declare **AuditorloginComponent** to any module which you want to use it in.

Comment: had you imported **AuditorloginModule** to the target module ?

Comment: Why imported  AuditorloginModule to app.module.ts?

Comment: If i will import AuditorloginModule to app.module.ts.its will not generated AuditorloginModule.chunk.js files

Comment: I didn't mean to app.module.ts , For example if you want to share X module for Z and Y module , you should import X for both modules and export X components in X module.

Answer (score 0):

Make it sure that your component is imported in app-routing.module.ts. In my case that it was the reason where
I forgot to include the component in the deceleration

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    IndexComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpClientModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Also make sure you restart server when new modules and components are added while ng serve it is also a reaosn when this problem occur.
So, the basic solution is to quit the server and ng serve again.